# Unity LineRenderer - unable to get reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a Unity scene with a LineRenderer in it at the top level (ie not child of some component), called "LineOfFlight".

I am trying to get a reference to it programmatically (not via the editor):

```
    LineRenderer
            lineOfFlight;
    GameObject
            tmp = GameObject.Find("LineOfFlight");

    if (tmp != null)
        lineOfFlight = tmp.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    Debug.Log("lineOfFlight=" + (lineOfFlight == null ? "null" : "not null") + ", tmp=" + (tmp == null ? "null" : tmp.ToString()));
```

In the debug log, tmp comes out as 'LineOfFlight (UnityEngine.GameObject)', which looks OK, but lineOfFlight comes out as 'null'. Ie could not get hold of the component.

I am doing all this in Awake(). What have I done wrong?

Comment: can you please include the full code as you have it in your file without editing anything out, including the functions they are in etc. right now we have incomplete information to your problem, as the code itself seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error somewhere in a part of your code that you have not included in your question, as the code itself is working when formatted properly, and set within functions.

Alternatively your `GameObject` called "LineOfFlight" may have a typo in its name, or does not have a `LineRenderer` component added to it.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class LineRendererText : MonoBehaviour
{

    LineRenderer lineOfFlight = null;

    private void Start()
    {
        GameObject tmp = GameObject.Find("LineOfFlight");

        if (tmp != null)
            lineOfFlight = tmp.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        Debug.Log("lineOfFlight=" + (lineOfFlight == null ? "null" : "not null") + ", tmp=" + (tmp == null ? "null" : tmp.ToString()));
    }
}
```

[image: Result when running]